# overwriting CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX

Tags: cmake

I have this piece of CMake code:

`if ( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT )
       set ( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install" )
    endif()
    message ( "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: " ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} )`

The first time I run cmake it correctly shows CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX pointing to my build_dir/install

The second time I run cmake, it gets back to /usr/local.

What's wrong ?

Comment: So it seems using CACHE FORCE fiex issue for me.

   if ( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT )

       set ( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install" 

   CACHE PATH "Install dir" FORCE)

   endif()

   message ( "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: " ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} )

p.s. Sorry, don't know how to format code in comment

Comment: Comments are not for multiline code. As the questions's author, you may add the code directly into the question post (by editing it).